# How to simulate a warehouse without using Rackpick/store or Dynamic Systems?

Tags: process, simulation, anylogic, stock, warehouse

I would like to simulate a warehouse as part of a process, like using a RackStore, but without linking it to a PalletRack, where in my input they can be agents. I made a quick illustration in relation to my question, maybe it will help to understand.

[Simulation of Warehouse like a process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbW6p.png)

Regards!

Comment: you can use seize-move-release as long as you don't use the built-in pallet racks and you make your own

Comment: But why though? Why not still use RackStore, and use the actions of it to do the required activities on your rack-representing agents (possibly with one arbitrary 'dummy' Pallet Rack that isn't visible)? You'll need to explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve and why you think RackStore / RackPick can't work for you.

Comment: Felipe, Stuart, thanks for your answers. I do not handle English very well, but I will try to explain the situation as much as I can. I want to simulate the entry, storage and exit of tons of Copper for some cities, however, I must link it directly to other processes that take tons of copper (agent) such as trucks and trains that would arrive at certain hours of the day to the copper warehouses. Another important factor to consider is that there are probabilities of arrival at the warehouses of the different cities, so the copper flow varies depending on the route you take.

Comment: The problem with the RackStore is that I have to allocate movable resources, nodes, paths, etc. that are not useful within my objective. However, you could use the RackStore / Pick with invisible PalletRacks, it is a good idea.